# Google Chrome CSE Custom Search Engine after installing updates

Tags: google-chrome

Yesterday I installed updates on my install of Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty, and started googling in the address bar of Google Chrome and suddenly got a new CSE (Custom Search Engine) design instead my usual search. In Chrome Settings > Search there appeared a new icon and the mouseover tooltip reads

```
"This option is enabled by the administrator"
```

so I can't change that CSE.

Trying reinstall Chrome but it makes nothing - CSE returns again.

What should I do to get back to my normal search?

http://higgs.rghost.ru/6G5H2yqPH/image.png

http://tau.rghost.ru/8GZvnwMmN/image.png

Answer (score 1):

https://superuser.com/questions/643641/how-to-revert-to-default-google-search-from-google-com-cse

I've found the answer at last..

do this in terminal

**locate chrome.json**

it will return a path

**sudo nano [the path]**

in my condition, it will return /etc/chromium-browser/policies/managed/chrome.json

then, change the content with this

```
{    
  "DefaultSearchProviderEnabled": true,    
  "DefaultSearchProviderInstantURL": "http://www.google.com/search?q={searchTerms}", 
  "DefaultSearchProviderKeyword": "google.com",    
  "DefaultSearchProviderName": "Google",    
  "DefaultSearchProviderSearchURL": "http://www.google.com/search?q={searchTerms}",  
  "DefaultSearchProviderSuggestURL": "http://www.google.com/search?q={searchTerms}" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the option with the google icon and click `set as default`

Comment: There is no such option. All I can do - just edit fileds "name" and "URL", nothing more.

Comment: @returngosu This is strange, because I have this button - just checked it.

Comment: @returngosu What does the tooltip say?

Comment: Have no any tooltip.

Comment: @returngosu I mean [this tooltip](http://dl.bmicraft.net/Pictures/tooltip.png). What does it say?

Comment: "This parameter is set ON by Administrator". Look, man, it's not about oneclick checkbox solution, it's kinda major changes after f* updates.

Comment: @returngosu Is this really google chrome, or chromium? If it is Google chrome, you may be better off contacting their support team. They exist for a reason.

Comment: You can however try to rename Chrome's config: `mv ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.config/google-chrome.old/` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Still have CSE after move.
I would try to contact Google support as you advice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @returngosu purge chrome: `apt-get purge google-chrome-stable` and reinstall `apt-get install google-chrome-stable`

Comment: I did it yet TWICE!

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to help you any further.